# What is the difference between $V=Es$ and $V=-Es$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electrons, charge, voltage

I have been using the equation $V=Es$ for all my calculations and have gotten it right. However, everything now has a negative sign including the equations from online as well as textbooks. When do I use which equation and why is there now a negative sign?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Is $V$ electric potential in a parallel plate capacitor, $E$ the corresponding electric field? If so, then the first equation just relates the *magnitudes* of the quantities, whereas the second also relates the direction (of $E$) and to the change in $V$ (so that $\vec{E}$ points in the direction of decreasing electric potential).

Comment: What does the s in Es stand for?

Comment: Es stands for Electric field and distance. So basically they are the same except the last equation (with neg) indicates change in(final-initial) which would give me a negative value since Vf is smaller then Vi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric field is the negative gradient of the potential, or, in cartesian coordinates:

$$\vec E=-\nabla V=-\biggl (\frac {\partial V}{\partial x}\hat {i}+\frac {\partial V}{\partial y}\hat {j}+\frac {\partial V}{\partial x}\hat {k}\biggr )$$

The electric field is the negative of the gradient because it points in the direction in which the potential energy function is decreasing. If you are only interested in calculating the magnitude of the field or potential, then you need not consider the sign. An example is the magnitude of the potential of a parallel plate capacitor where the field is considered constant. Then $V=Ed$ where $d$ is the distance between the plates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So whenever I am finding E field with the negative sign equation the negative indicates if the proton when to higher potential or lower along with the gain/loss of potential? The one without the negative sign just indicates the number of how much potential it gaine/lost?

Comment: @Muse The direction of the electric field is, by convention, the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field.  Consider the electric field in a parallel plate air capacitor. The field points in the direction from the positively charged plate to the negatively charged plate because if a positive charge were placed near the positive plate it would experience a force in the direction of the negative plate.

Comment: In going from the positively charged plate to the negatively charged plate there is  a drop (negative change) in potential, thus the negative sign. But the magnitude of the potential difference (voltage) between the plates does not depend on which direction you go. That’s because voltage is a scalar, not vector, quantity. The gradient of a scalar is quantity is a vector quantity.